# If statement to open a link in new tab

Tags: php

Is this correct? Basically I want to open a link in new tab if the link type is external. Otherwise don't open it in new tab if the link type is embed.

I have two link types:

1. External
2. Embed

The following code doesn't open the external link_type in new tab

```
<a id="sample" href="sample.com">This is a link <?php if($t_link->link_type == 'External') echo target="_blank href="sample.com"; ?> </a>
```

Comment: The `if` should be inside `<a>` while assigning attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <?php if($t_link->link_type == 'External')
    echo "<a target='_blank' href='http://www.sample.com'> This is an external link</a>";
 else 
    echo "<a  href='sample.com'> This is an internal link</a>";
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 switch($t_link->link_type){
 case "External":
 echo "<a id='sample' href='sample.com' target='_blank'></a>";
 break;
 case "Embed":
 echo "<a id='sample' href='sample.com' ></a>";
 break;

 }
```

Comment: My explanation is on Tintu C Raju's comment :) I am very new to php

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix, This is now my code and it work perfectly:

```
<a target="_blank" href="<?=get_option('url') ?>/wpwm-redirect?link_id=<?=$t_link->linkID ?>"<?php if($t_link->link_type == 'Embed') echo ' id="default-video" onclick="ayeLoadVideo(\'/wpwm-redirect?link_id=' . $t_link->linkID . '\'); return false;"'; ?>> <?=$t_link->link_title ?>  </a>
```